# Координаты Scene2D

Tags: java, libgdx

Я использую `FitViewport` с виртуальным размером 1920х1080.

```
viewport = new FitViewport(AssetLoader.VIRTUAL_WIDTH, AssetLoader.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
stage = new Stage(viewport);
```

Также есть кастомный актер, унаследованный от класса `Actor`. Ниже приведен код его конструктора.

```
public MyActor(String text, float x, float y) {
    this.text = text;

    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(AssetLoader.robotoFontFile);
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 96;
    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose();
    layout = new GlyphLayout();
    layout.setText(font, text);
    super.setBounds(x, y, layout.width, layout.height);

    this.debug();
    renderer = new ShapeRenderer();


    this.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("MyActor", text + " is touched!");
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

И переопределенный метод `draw`:

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    batch.end();

    renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    this.drawDebugBounds(renderer);
    renderer.end();

    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, text, getX(), getY());

}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при запуске получается это:

[image: bounds strange behavior]

А нажатие срабатывает, только если жать внутрь зеленого прямоугольника, хотя подразумевалось, что зеленый прямоугольник и текст будут накладываться.

Возможно, проблема с трансляцией, но ничего годного я не смог найти, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самым простым решением оказалось добавить высоту текста к его y-координате:

```
font.draw(batch, text, getX(), getY() + layout.heigth);
```